# How to GET list based on a string input

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I want to list groups by there associated tags I am using a textbox to represent the TagName which is related to my GET method in my Service. On my client side I have this:

```
string uriGetGroupsCollection = "http://localhost:8000/Service/GetGroupsCollection/{TagName}";
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(uriGetGroupsCollection);
    var Tag = xDoc.Descendants("notsure")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            Tag = n.Element("notsure").Value,
        })
        .ToList();

    dataGridView3.DataSource = Tag;
}
```

This only returns a list of tags how can I change it so it will take a string from my textbox and return a list of groups into my datagrid? Id preferably want it so on button click my datagrid is populated with Tag and a list of groups associated with that TagName.

Abit like how SO has tags associated with questions, if you click on any of the tags next to this question it will list questions related to that tag, in the same sense I want to achieve the same goal but instead of questions its groups.

Comment: Very confusing indeed. Can you at least indicate what part runs on the server and what on the client?  And where does that TextBox come in?

Comment: FirstOrDefault takes a predicate as well. So you don't need to have a where first; just combine. Such as: Groups.FirstOrDefault(n => String.Equals(n.GroupName, tag))

Comment: This question is confusing. Why not provide an example of the data (not the process that created the data, nor the output screen shot of the GUI that holds the view), just the data and ask how to arrange it to be bindable? I don't see any data example. ???

Comment: Using StringBuilder to create an Xml text? When XDocument is in the question-title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need

```
string uriGetGroupsCollection = 
     "http://localhost:8000/Service/GetGroupsCollection/{TagName}";

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tagUri = uriGetGroupsCollection.Replace("{TagName}", textbox1.text);
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(tagUri);
    ...
}
```

Comment: ugh getting 404 not found so something buggy is up with my GetGroupsCollection.